# How to save a session in a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt4

I made this tool in Qt Creator where i have to enter some data in spin boxes and combo boxes. Each of these boxes have a default value when I open my tool. But I would like to implement a function to save the session of the application, i.e. if i modify some values in the boxes i can save them and when I open my application again my modifications are there. And also when I am done with that data I can restore the defaults.

Any idea as to how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [QSettings](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qsettings.html) , it's usage is explained in the page